# Cannot access to correct http request with heroku backend api

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, heroku, router

I'm running a SpringBoot app on heroku, and I feel like Heroku redirect all the request from my react frontend.
For example, I'm using the HttpRequestServlet locale to determine which language I use or even request.getServerName() for setting urls and for every request it returns the heroku url (xxx.herokuapp.com). I feel like every of my request are redirected by a router or something. How can I get rid of that and get the correct frontend request with correct informations ?

Comment: What do you expect it to return? here you can read about all heroku networking https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#routing

Comment: let's say my frontned url is https://frontend.com, when I use HttpServletRequest.getServerName(), i expect to get "frontend", but instead I get backend (if my backend url is https://backend.com) and even if my request contains Locale fr, I get "en" with heroku since they're based in Ireland or whatever english country it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation for [ServletRequest#getServerName](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName()) it reads.

> Returns the host name of the server to which the request was sent.

Not the name of the sending client. So this is expected behaviour.

And in the documentation for [ServletRequest#getLocale](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale()) it reads

> Returns an Enumeration of Locale objects indicating, in decreasing order starting with the preferred locale, the locales that are acceptable to the client based on the Accept-Language header. **If the client request doesn't provide an Accept-Language header, this method returns an Enumeration containing one Locale, the default locale for the server**.

So if you have not set a preferred Locale in the `Accept-Language` header when sending the request from the client, then it will return the servers current Locale.

Comment: True for the first one ServletRequest#getServerName, my bad since I used localhost for development it was still working. But still, for the getLocale I did setup Accept-Language: fr inside header request, it's working locally but when deploying to heroku it returns english language ..

Comment: Ok, my bad again sorry, I was setting Accept-Language to "fr", but I do need to use "fr-FR". I'm a bit surprised since the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language saying as an example that I could just put "fr".